# Don't let change happen - Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, onchange

I have a very basic requirement but i do not know how to code this.
What I am looking for is, not to make any change happen in a particular Range("J10:J1000") if the cell is >=1. If that make sense.

So any cell from J10 to J1000 can change into any amount if it is 0 but if it is more than 0 then I want to display and message Saying that"Sorry! change can not happen."

Comment: Go to "Data" in your toolbar and click "Data Validation" and set the rules in there. No VBA needed here.[more info here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try.
Place the following codes on Sheet Module.

To do so, right click the Sheet Tab --> View Code and paste the codes given below into the opened code window --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

```
Dim oVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo SkipError
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J10:J1000")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then
        Application.Undo
    Else
        If oVal > 0 Then
            Application.Undo
            Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
            MsgBox "Sorry! you cannot change the cell content.", vbExclamation, "Change Not Allowed!"
        End If
    End If
End If
SkipError:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J10:J1000")) Is Nothing Then
    oVal = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome Naseer! Glad it worked. I think you missed to upvote the answer. :)

Comment: I am sorry! I am new in this site. How can I do that?

Comment: You see two arrows Up and Down next to my answer and there you can click the Up arrow to upvote it. :)

Comment: You did something wrong. As you can only do that once. Never mind. :)